# Handle Java method 'paused()' in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to expose Java method via Scala (more details on original java method - it is coming from [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#paused()))

This is original Java method:

```
pause(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

How to expose and pass parameters to a method in Scala and which Scala collection to use in this case? 
I have something like:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{KafkaConsumer, OffsetAndMetadata}
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import collection.mutable.Map
import collection.JavaConverters._

//initialise consumer:
var consumer = createKafkaConsumer(config, subscriptions)

//accept a scala.collection.mutable.Map here
def pauseMethod (topic_partition) = {
    //and then convert it to a java
    consumer.pause(topic_partition)
}
```

Also, how to call (and pass parameters) to this method in Scala?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are confusing `paused()` with `pause(Collection)`.  KafkaConsumer doesn't have a `paused(Collection)` function. You shouldn't have to expose anything so just call the `pause` function directly.

Using your limited code sample, you can pause and retrieve paused topics with the following

```
val consumer = createKafkaConsumer(config, subscription)

consumer.pause(Seq("topic1","topic2").asJava)
println(consumer.paused().asScala)
```

Note that the Scala collection is converted to java using `asJava` and the the Java collection is converted to Scala using the inverse function `asScala`.

Hopefully this is what you are after, otherwise please provide a minimally functional code sample along with clarifying question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. To clarify - I am new to some legacy code made in Java that talks to Kafka. Now trying to add to Scala library for users who use only Scala to talk to Java and Kafka.. Not yet familiar with all but believe that all I have to do is to make a method in Scala that will be able to call Java method for pause (or maybe directly from Scala to Kafka for pause, for that part I am not sure yet).

Comment: Okay, in this case you don't need to do anything special to interact with Java from Scala.  Just use the `JavaConverters` library to convert your datatypes to and from Java (I generally like to avoid Java collections in my Scala code so I convert as soon as possible).

Comment: Do you have example how would method in Scala look like to enable calling Java `pause` method? Thanks.

Comment: My original answer is how you do it; specifically `consumer.pause(Seq("topic1","topic2").asJava)`.  There's nothing special for calling Java methods from Scala.  You just need to be sure and pass the correct datatype.  In my example, the `JavaConverters` library is used to convert a `Seq` to a Java collection (which the API expects).  If that's not working for you, please what errors you are seeing.